# User-Defined classes and methods

Tags: java

I am doing an assignment where I have to create a class Day that needs to do a series of things. I have everything figured out, most of it is pretty simple, but I am having one problem. One of the methods is supposed to let you set the day to whatever day of the week you want. For example, the program starts with the day set to Fri and I should be able to enter Mon and then tell it to output and it should output Mon. For some reason, it is not updating the day and I can't figure it out. Anybody see what I'm missing here?

```
The purpose of this program is to create a class Day that will perform
   multiple tasks regarding the day of the week. */

import java.util.*;


public class DayProgram
{
   static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


   public static class Day
   {
       String[] weekDays = {"Sun" , "Mon", "Tues", "Weds", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"};

      int setDay = 0;
      int returnDay = 0;

      public Day(String today)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < weekDays.length; i++)
         {
            if (today.equals(weekDays[i]))
               {
                  setDay = i;
                  return;
               }
         }
         System.out.println("That is not a valid day.");
      }

      public void printDay()
      {
         if (setDay <= weekDays.length)
         {
            System.out.println("Today is " + weekDays[setDay]);
         }
         else System.out.println("Day is not valid");
      }

      public String setDay()
      {
         String newDay = keyboard.next();
         return newDay;
      }

      public String tomorrow()
      {
         return weekDays[(setDay + 1)%weekDays.length];
      }

      public String yesterday()
      {
         return weekDays[(setDay - 1)%weekDays.length];
      }

      public String findDay(int x)
      {
         return weekDays[(setDay + x)%weekDays.length];
      } 

      public String returnDay()
      {
         return weekDays[setDay];
      }


     }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Day day = new Day("Fri");

       day.printDay();

       System.out.println("Please change the day of the week.");

       day.setDay();

       day.printDay();

       System.out.println(day.returnDay());

       System.out.println(day.tomorrow());

       System.out.println(day.yesterday());

       System.out.println("Please enter number of days and I will tell you what day of the week it will be.");

       System.out.println(day.findDay(keyboard.nextInt()));


    }        
}
```

Comment: `day = new Day(day.setDay());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDay()` doesn't modify the variable `setDay`. Simply change
`newDay = input.next()` to `setDay = input.next()` to make a persistent change to the object.

Comment: But I need to use the user-defined methods. That is the real point of the assignment. Thank you though!

Comment: @ethancodes then you'll have to either directly access `setDay` as a variable of your Day-Object, or overwrite the entire Day-Object with a new instance with the appropriate day. The provided `Day`-class is designed immutable except for direct variable-access (for whatever reason). That would be a helpful info in the overall question, please edit it.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to programming. What do you mean by immutable?

Comment: @ethancodes you can't change attributes of Objects of an immutable class. In your example there is no `set...`-method or anything provided that would manipulate the `setDay`-attribute, thus making it immutable - except for the fact that you can directly overwrite the attribute via a simple direct write like `day.setDay = 3;`. But that's rather bad code, like the provided class itself.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes sense. So my setDay method is basically completely wrong. How do I fix it?

Comment: @ethancodes thought you can't override any of the given methods? If you can, just replace it with `void setDay(){ setDay = input.next();}` to update the value with the value input by the user.

Comment: But setDay is an integer so how can I change it when the user input would be a day like Mon or Tues?

Comment: @ethancodes well, either you read an integer instead, or you'll have to search the index corresponding to the day-string the user entered. E.g. the index that corresponds to "Tues" is 2.

Comment: I believe I will need to do your second example of searching the day string. So i will need to create a loop to go through that array and when it equals what the user input, then at that point it would update to that.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks a ton! I learned a lot from this assignment. I do have one more question @Paul. Earlier you said the class as a whole was pretty bad code. I want to improve any way I can. If you wouldn't mind elaborating on where I should be doing different I would really appreciate any constructive criticism you could give me! Thanks again Paul!

Comment: @ethancodes in general it's recommendable to use one file per class, except for some specific cases, where inner classes are used (I'd recommend the java-tutorial on that topic for further reading). E.g. your `Day`-class should be in a separate file. OOP follows the principle of encapsulation. That means variables should be `private` and only accessible via the methods provided by the class to restrict access. And constants (like your `Day.weekDays`) should be declared as `static final`, since they're not supposed to be overwritten and aren't related to any specific instance.

Comment: @ethancodes I'd recommend you read a tutorial on code-style for further information. This one here isn't bad: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html , but there are other code-style guidelines out there aswell. In general it's always a good idea to read the oracle-tutorials on specific points of programs to understand the way they work and how they're supposed to be used.

Comment: We haven't learned about when to use private and public and also haven't learned about separate files. I know some about it because of previous experience before this class, but this is my first Java class and my first time using the JGRASP IDE so I'm still learning some of this stuff. I will definitely read this tutorial though in my free time to improve on this stuff. Thanks again! You were a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String setDay()
  {
     String newDay = keyboard.next();
     return newDay;
  }
```

You initialize theh local variable 'newDay', but don't assign it to 'setDay'.

You return that newDay, but nobody catches the result.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. I tried to fix it several different ways but can't seem to get it. Since day is of type Day, I can't seem to figure out how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Change at:

```
System.out.println("Please change the day of the week.");

day.setDay();

day.printDay();

day.setDay();
```

To:

```
day.Day(day.setDay());
```

I don't know if you can set this `day.setDay` function into this. If it doesn't work just use an extra variable.

By the way, I'm not sure if this is right I just used your thing to learn this user defined method/class thing for myself.